# How to hide an image with a clear pixel

Tags: css, image, pixel

When I go to Google shopping( http://www.google.com/prdhp ) and right click on the little 4 colored tag image and select View Image(Firefox) I get this in the URL bar, and no image: http://www.google.com/prdhp/clear.cache.gif , it is just a 1x1 clear dot.
How can I implement a similar technique? What would this be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possibilities for solving this, but all work the same: Place your real image on the page, and add another image (which is in fact a transparent gif) above your real image. You could solve it this way:

```
<div style="background-image:url(realimage.png); width:400px; height:300px;">
    <img src="transparent.gif" alt="" style="width:400px; height:300px;" />
</div>
```

This will be a more robust way to prevent image stealing, but you could also put the real image as an `img` tag onto your site and position the transparent gif as an `img` tag absolute over the real `img`.

Comment: So I could make all my images sprites and then overlay them with cleardots?

Comment: You could also leave your site as it is, and place a BIG `<img src="transparent.gif" alt="" style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" />` over your complete site. (But thats NOT user friendly!)

Comment: does not prevent image stealing ... hinders it by 1 or 2 clicks.

Comment: It will prevent normal internet users from stealing the image. The link to the image is of course still in the source code of the page. But there is practically no way to prevent image stealing. Base64 encoded images could be converted using some tools, or the simplest way: just screenshot the website and crop the image.

Comment: hence the hindering part. NOT preventing.

Answer (score 2):

It's an image element with the gif you mentioned that has another image as a background using uri with the encoded image data. background:url(data:image/png, base64, `everything that follows here is a base64 encoded string with the image data`), but as you can see it's only a neat trick that does bupkiss

[image]

What gets on the web stays on the web.

Decoding a base64 string into binary data can be done if you are familiar with either `base64.decodestring(string)` (for python) or PHP's `base64_decode($data)` or .NET's `byte[] byteArr = Convert.FromBase64String(data)`. Take your pick. There are also sites that offer this service for free for some weird reason.

Comment: How were you able to get that image?

Comment: it's written in the answer above ... base64 png uri ... info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by loading the 1x1 pixel in the `<img>` tag and then use Javascript to replace the image. Another technique would be with CSS by loading the image as a background for some container, and then forcing the 1x1 pixel `<img>` to stretch to the size of the container element.